# Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency on build a nextjs app - mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I ran `npm run build` in my nextjs project and i saw this error

`Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency`

> Build error occurred
> Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
> at build (D:\projects\frontend_vaghtebazi\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:15:918)
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

my next.config.js file:

```js
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
const lessToJS = require('less-vars-to-js');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withOptimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

// Where your antd-custom.less file lives
const themeVariables = lessToJS(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './static/styles/antd.less'), 'utf8'));

const plugins = [
  withOptimizedImages,
  [
    // withOptimizedImages,
    withLess({
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
      },
      webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        if (isServer) {
          const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
          const origExternals = [...config.externals];
          config.externals = [
            (context, request, callback) => {
              if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
              if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
                origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
              } else {
                callback();
              }
            },
            ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
          ];

          config.module.rules.unshift({
            test: antStyles,
            use: 'null-loader',
          });
        }

        const builtInLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => {
          if (rule.oneOf) {
            return (
              rule.oneOf.find((deepRule) => {
                return deepRule.test && deepRule.test.toString().includes('/a^/');
              }) !== undefined
            );
          }
          return false;
        });

        if (typeof builtInLoader !== 'undefined') {
          config.module.rules.push({
            oneOf: [
              ...builtInLoader.oneOf.filter((rule) => {
                return (rule.test && rule.test.toString().includes('/a^/')) !== true;
              }),
            ],
          });
        }

        config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.resolve(__dirname);
        return config;
      },
    }),
  ],
];

const nextConfig = {
  env: {},
};

module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, nextConfig);
```

Tried finding solutions online and found [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/493) that a missing `mini-css-extract-plugin` configuration might raise this error. But i was confused, because its not working. how can i solve that?

Comment: any solution to this problem? I am facing it too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

#### Solutions

When using [next-compose-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-compose-plugins) you need to export all plugins alongside their config inside the `withPlugin()` functions as follow:

```
exports.module = withPlugin([[withOptimizedImages, { ... }], [withLess, {
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
      },
      webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        if (isServer) {
          const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
          const origExternals = [...config.externals];
          config.externals = [
            (context, request, callback) => {
              if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
              if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
                origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
              } else {
                callback();
              }
            },
            ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
          ];

          config.module.rules.unshift({
            test: antStyles,
            use: 'null-loader',
          });
        }

        const builtInLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => {
          if (rule.oneOf) {
            return (
              rule.oneOf.find((deepRule) => {
                return deepRule.test && deepRule.test.toString().includes('/a^/');
              }) !== undefined
            );
          }
          return false;
        });

        if (typeof builtInLoader !== 'undefined') {
          config.module.rules.push({
            oneOf: [
              ...builtInLoader.oneOf.filter((rule) => {
                return (rule.test && rule.test.toString().includes('/a^/')) !== true;
              }),
            ],
          });
        }

        config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.resolve(__dirname);
        return config;
      },
    }]], nextConfig);
```

If you still face this issue or another, you can still use the [next-plugin-antd-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-plugin-antd-less) package, and with [next-compose-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-compose-plugins),
It seems this package has a workaround for this `mini-css-extract-plugin` issue.
You need to follow the same structure as the `@zeit/next-less`:

```
module.exports = withPlugins([
  [withOptimizedImages],
  [
    withAntdLess,
    {
      lessVarsFilePath: "./static/styles/antd.less",
    },
  ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use **reactjs** and this happened when using the **npm run build** command, and the reason for **this error** was using the function for the **wrong address** in service-worker.ts

> The following code is wrong:

```
createHandlerBoundToURL(PublicFunctions.GetPublicUrl() + '/index.html')
```

> The following code is correct:

```
createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
// Or
createHandlerBoundToURL('/index.html')
```